# Getting raw payload of DNS packets using scapy

Tags: python-2.7, dns, scapy, payload

I'm trying to extract all UDP and TCP payloads from a pcap file using `packet[TCP].payload.load` and `packet[UDP].payload.load`. However, I noticed that `packet[UDP].payload.load` failed for DNS packets.

The output of `packet[IP].show()` is as follows (one DNS query and response packet). I don't see any `[ Raw ]` section, which I guess is where the `.load` failed. How can I extract the payload in bytes after the UDP layer for such packets?

```
====================================================
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 64
  id        = 59183
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 128
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0x0
  src       = 172.22.32.48
  dst       = 203.211.152.66
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = 55884
     dport     = domain
     len       = 44
     chksum    = 0x309a
###[ DNS ]### 
        id        = 40212
        qr        = 0
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 0
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 1
        ra        = 0
        z         = 0
        <snipped>

None
====================================================
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 155
  id        = 38148
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 58
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0xbaf1
  src       = 203.211.152.66
  dst       = 172.22.32.48
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 55884
     len       = 135
     chksum    = 0x51d9
###[ DNS ]### 
        id        = 40212
        qr        = 1
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 0
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 1
        ra        = 1
        <snipped>

None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scapy has dissected the DNS layer into something meaningful. If you want the raw bytes, you can call `bytes()` on a layer to get them back.

For instance:

```
bytes(packet[TCP].payload)
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I could also do `binascii.hexlify(str(packet[UDP].payload))` to print the hex characters out in ASCII.